# Extracting an embedded file from excel using Php on linux

Tags: php, excel

Hi and thanks for reading.

I have an excel spreadsheet that has files inserted into 1 column, and I'm looking for a way to pull them out with php so that I can then copy them to another directory.

So far I've had a look at PhpExcel and ExcelReader but unless I'm missing something, I cant see anywhere in the respective API's that details how to extract files. I have seen some code for getting hyperlinks and PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing and PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing, but nothing for general files.

Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so using what utility class? Or even better, could someone please show me a sample piece of code.

Thanks again for reading,
Ian

Comment: What kind of a file? How is it embedded into the document - using DDE or whatever is used these days? Or is it a link?

Comment: Hi Pekka, My file is an xls file and the files were inserted/embedded (?) by using the options 'Insert - Object - Create from file' in excel. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

IF the Excel files are `XLSX` (2007 / 2010) then just `unzip` them since they are zip files with a folder structure and several XMLs inside... and somewhere in the structure there the embedded files...

the folder inside the Excel file containing embedded files is called `xl/embeddings/`

IF for some reason you need to handle older formats (`XLS`) and/or need some feature in working with Excel files you will need a 3rd-party library... one example is Aspose.Cells for Java which can access/extract/add embedded files (=OLE objects, see http://www.aspose.com/documentation/java-components/aspose.cells-for-java/com/aspose/cells/oleobject.html#getObjectData%28%29) and has a PHP interface, see http://www.aspose.com/documentation/java-components/aspose.cells-for-java/aspose-cells-for-java-php.html

Comment: Hi Yahia, the file is an excel xls file and the files were inserted/embedded (?) by using the options 'Insert - Object - Create from file' in excel.

Comment: OK - then you will need a 3rd-party library... checkout the part of my answer AFTER `xl/embeddings/` .

Comment: Hi Yahia, thanks for the reply. I dont suppose you know of any php libraries that will do this? Sadly it has to be Php...

Comment: no - I don't - but the one I mentioned (is Java) has a PHP... file formats are tather complicated, esp. the "old" Office formats and esp. the OLE object (embeddeed files) part...

Comment: you don't need a library at all IF you can make your users give you more current Excel files (xlsx, Excel 2007 or newer)...

Comment: @yahia when you extract the embedded files, even if it uses the modern file format, most have been converted to have a .bin file extension and are in the OLE-Object format, not the original file format. It must be converted with a library first. Test it out by embedding a PDF inside the Excel and see for yourself.